# Where is the "gentleman" to locate in Memory 02 of Freedom Cry?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

As the question states. I see no golden target in the green area using Eagle Vision. Have I been looking in the wrong spots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Near the slave auction just outside the green zone (North East).

Video (at the 17 minute mark):